# Faster way of replacing bigger matrix values with smaller matrix values given indices?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, for-loop, matrix

Is there a faster way of performing this?

Dimensions are:

- `proj`: 400 x 400
- `bigproj`: 30k x 30k
- `totalproj`: 30k x 30k

`ds1` and `ds2` (each of shape: 6k x 400) are matrices extracted from larger matrices (`DS1` and `DS2`) where each is of shape 6k x 30k . `proj` is the result of some function performed on `ds1` and `ds2`. `origindex` are the column indices of `DS1` or `DS2`

```
ds1 = DS1[:,origindex]
ds2 = DS2[:,origindex]
proj = somefunction(ds1,ds2)

for m, n in product(range(proj.shape[0]), range(proj.shape[1])):
    bigproj[origindex[m], origindex[n]] = proj[m, n]  
    totalproj += bigproj
```

Seems like the last line adding the matrices takes the longest.

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Did you mean to perform the summation of the *full* matrix `bigproj` on *every* iteration of the loop? This accumulates previously set values via `proj`. Or did you mean to use `totalproj[origindex[m], origindex[n]] += bigproj[origindex[m], origindex[n]]` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can vectorize the first part of the loop via [`np.mgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html):

```
m, n = proj.shape
bigproj[tuple(origindex[np.mgrid[:m, :n]])] = proj
```

If you really meant to perform the second part as written (`totalproj += bigproj`), i.e. to add the *current* version of `bigproj` on *every* iteration you can do that via:

```
bigproj[tuple(origindex[np.mgrid[:m, :n]])] = proj * np.arange(1, m*n+1).reshape(m, n)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the bigproj and totalproj are list of lists, then the default behavior of += will append all of the items from one list onto another. So each iteration of that loop, totalproj is growing by 30000 x 30000 elements.

Since it looks like you are only changing a single element in each iteration of the loop, I would look to see if you can just store the changes separately and either add them or extend your matrix as needed once the loop is complete.